# Firing events in script task

Tags: c#, ssis

I've got an SSIS project where I am constructing an SQL command based on some variables. I'm constructing the command in a script task, and want to output the constructed SQL to the 'Execution Results' window. I am trying to do this using a FireInformation line from inside my script as follows:

```
Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "Make this event appear!", "", 0, true);
```

However, in the script editor when editing ScriptMain.cs, that line is underlined in red, and on mouseover, I get the following message:

> Error:
>   The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.EventsObjectWrapper.FireInformation(int, string, string, string, int, ref bool') has some invalid arguments

As a result, my script does not compile and I cannot execute it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here, or what I need to change to be able to see the values of my variables at this point in the Execution output?

Comment: Upvoted because this question helped me to realize that Dts.events.FireInformation does not update the windows event log.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The last parameter of [IDTSComponentEvents.FireInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtscomponentevents.fireinformation.aspx) is a `ref bool`, not a `bool`.

So you need to pass a reference to a variable of type `bool` instead of a `bool` value:

```
bool fireAgain = true;
Dts.Events.FireInformation(..., ref fireAgain);
```

Answer (score 10):

You need the `ref` keyword:

```
bool b = true;
Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "Make this event appear!", "", 0, ref b);
```