# Is there a way to cause OnError to fire with no error

Tags: ssis

I want to make the OnError event handler fire with custom values. In other words, I want to raise an error. Is there a way to do that in SSIS?

There is no actual error condition. It would be an error in business logic that I would like to handle with the error handling procedures I've already established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a script task and call the [Dts.Events.FireError](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtscomponentevents.fireerror.aspx) method

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx
- [Firing events in script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037693/firing-events-in-script-task)
- http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/11/03/SSIS_3A00_-Throwing-errors-from-script-task_2F00_component.aspx